# Unlink js file after execution

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, unlink

I want to remove my scripts file after it executes. It should be removed from all session. I linked file in functions.php for child theme:

```
function tutsplus_enqueue_custom_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/scripts/redirect.js');
}
```

As I said - it should be executed only once in whole session, not page. I know that it should be done with `unlink` but I don't know how to write a condition that will remove this file from whole session only when it was executed . Can you help me?

new script:

```
let executed = window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionCodeExecuted")
console.log(executed)
if (executed != 1) {
let uri = window.location;
let lang = window.navigator.language;

if( uri.href.indexOf('lang') < 0) {
if ((lang != 'ru-RU') && (lang != 'ru')){
eng = window.location.href.includes('https://www.site/en/');

if (eng == false){
let re = "https://www.site/";
let url = window.location.href;
let newstr = url.replace(re, 'https://www.site/en/');
newstr += "?currency=USD";
window.location.href = newstr;
}

}
}
window.sessionStorage.setItem("sessionCodeExecuted", 1);
}
```

Comment: You could set a session variable after you've added the script. Then you can check if that session variable is set or not. If it isn't, load the script, if it exists, don't load the script. That way it will only be added on the first page load for every session. If you meant the PHP command `unlink()`, that will completely delete the file from the system, which is probably not what you want?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm working with wordpress. I don't know where session variable is. Can I delete file just for current user, not from system?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edited functions.php. I added this in the beggining: `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tutsplus_enqueue_custom_js');
function tutsplus_enqueue_custom_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/scripts/redirect.js');
}
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}` Nothing changed

Comment: Why don't you use sessionStorage for this? You can store a value there on first page load and make a check at the beginning of the js file `redirect.js` to return early if a value exists in sessionStorage (script has been executed.)

Comment: @Badan I edited question as you said (added script). `console.log` writes `1` but is script still running. What is wrong?

Comment: _"I'm working with wordpress. I don't know where session variable is"_ -  Just google "use sessions in wordpress" and I bet you will find many many posts about it. The code you posted in your comment does not do what I suggested. A big (BIG) part of being a developer is doing a lot of research. And no, you can't delete a file for only one user, unless you create a separate file per user (which would be crazy). Either the file exists or it doesn't. Different users/sessions don't have different file systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to check if the script has been executed and store this info there. Then, do a check if the value exists. If it does, prevent the code from executing on next page reload. Please note that when you close and reopen the browser, the code will execute again (it seems this is exactly what you need).

```
(function(){
  let executed = window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionCodeExecuted");

  if (!sessionStorage.getItem('sessionCodeExecuted')) {
      sessionStorage.setItem('sessionCodeExecuted', 'yes');
  }
  
  if (executed) return;

  /* below script will execute only once during the current browser session. */

  let uri = window.location;
  let lang = window.navigator.language;

  if (uri.href.indexOf('lang') < 0) {
      if ((lang != 'ru-RU') && (lang != 'ru')) {
          eng = window.location.href.includes('https://www.site/en/');

          if (eng == false) {
              let re = "https://www.site/";
              let url = window.location.href;
              let newstr = url.replace(re, 'https://www.site/en/');
              newstr += "?currency=USD";
              window.location.href = newstr;
          }

      }
  }
})();
```

Comment: I had similar code in my question and they are both don't prevent from second redirection. It's keeping redirection

Comment: Let me test it, I might have made a mistake.

Comment: I just tested the code, it does store the value in the `sessionStorage` and if you add `console.log('here')` after `if (executed) return;` line, you will see that it will not print anything the second time you reload the page. Note that it will still run the script on every page load until it reaches the return statement. Can you clear your browser cache and try once again?

Comment: I add `console.log('here')` and it really showed only once, but script still is running every time (even if I reload page and then try to change a language). I cleared cache before that.

Comment: I forgot to add `let` for `eng` but when I added, nothing changed

Comment: That is really weird, check if you did not forget to remove this script from somewhere else. As you can see with `console.log`, nothing past the return statement in this file will execute more than one time. Could it be this code messes with the urls somehow?

Comment: I wrote this script in header.php (wordpress file) so it runs on every page of site. URL of this site works perfectly if script just adds `/en/`. You can check this out: https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/

Comment: Check your code again, you are appending `en ` and `?currency=USD` string to the url before the return statement

Comment: I'm sorry mate, your code was right, wordpress saved my previous code in cache (not browser cache but wordpress). Thank you a lot for your answer and thank you for staying with me for hour!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!